# PWA add to home screen feature not working on mozilla firefox

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, mozilla, angular-service-worker

My Angular PWA app "Add to home screen" feature works fine for chrome in mobile but the same is not working for mozilla firefox, i have checked manifest.json and service worker as well.

I am able to create a shortcut for my website but I am not able to install it as an application

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe  your PWA does not run from a HTTPS domain, or your service worker is not registred properly in your JS file. However, Mozilla just annouced dropping any PWA support in Firefox desktop browsers because their SSB code were buggy (which is not the fault of PWA). So it would be not a suprise they do it in mobile versions too. Consider to inform your users when they approach your website with Firefox by showing them a popup message containing an advice to move to Edge or Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for the information @JoSa400 my PWA is registered on HTTPS, I guess it was not working because of the firefox issue which you mentioned.